# Footer Caching Workaround.. what's the right way to do this?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have the following chunk of code in my footer.phtml

```
 <!-- Customer Modal -->
 <?php if (array_key_exists("customer_select", $_COOKIE) == FALSE ): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?=$this->getSkinUrl('js/jqModal.js')?>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#customer_type_dialog").jqm().jqmShow();
        });
    </script>
    <?php include("../../templates.eu/templates.sbc.de/_includes/customer_select.php"); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I turn on the block caching it stops evaluating this an only returns the value that was cached. HOw do I work around this problem or what is a better way to do this? Basically I'm checking to see if a cookie exists and if it does I'm adding some js and another file to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the above code in it's own template file and make this layout change:

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
    <block type="core/template" template="your/cookie/check/file.phtml" />
</reference>
```

This way the footer gets to be cached (which helps keep pages fast) and your cookie check is evaluated each time. Also the Javascript is left until the last possible point of the page which is a best practice for inline scripts.

Comment: where would I put that layout change?  In page.xml? Should I create it's own layout file?

Comment: Either will work equally well, it depends on personal taste. Some people say to use `local.xml` always but if it's for a module you are writing then it should go in a `modulename.xml`. I think if your theme depends on it then it's acceptable to put it directly in `page.xml`. Also it should be positioned inside either a `<default>` layout handle or something more page specific like `<catalog_product_view>` or whatever...

Comment: I eneed up putting the statement right in the <default> section, but it appears to be working fine.